# My USB is not imaging properly

Tags: partitioning, usb, disk-image

I have a dual boot system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu, Windows fast boot is off), and thus have many partitions on my hard disk. At boot, the USB drive is imaging fine on Ubuntu, and is working in all of the ways you would expect it too.

However, when I mount the Microsoft data partition of my hard disk (at least I'm almost sure that's the cause), you can no longer format the USB or image it in any way.

I've tried `dd`, in fact, that's where I need it to work because using `dd` is much easier than using the Ubuntu Startup Disk creator (I am designing an operating system in case anyone wanted to know, and it is HARD ENOUGH WITHOUT USB PROBLEMS!!!). I can't mount it because it lacks a file system from the last imaging. Although, if I format it before I access Microsoft (or the error that occurs that you will see in a moment), it works fine as a regular USB disk. I just cant re-format it.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Please ask me if you have any questions or need to see more details.

Commands:

```
root@my_comp:/# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             6100104       0   6100104   0% /dev
tmpfs            1224076    9820   1214256   1% /run
/dev/sda5      382559396 9121780 353981616   3% /
tmpfs            6120368   51716   6068652   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            6120368       0   6120368   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         262144   30636    231508  12% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1224076      48   1224028   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0         4442656 4442656         0 100% /media/devepere/BOPC_1E1
```

This makes sense since there isn't actually a file system on the disk: it's completely overwritten and I haven't implemented a FAT table in my bootloader yet.

```
root@my_comp:/# parted -ls
Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          
Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          
boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB                  Microsoft reserved 
partition  msftres
 3      290MB   589GB   588GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          
msftdata
 5      589GB   987GB   398GB   ext4
 6      987GB   1000GB  12.8GB  linux-swap(v1)
 4      1000GB  1000GB  523MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          
hidden, diag


Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1028MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1028MB  1027MB  primary


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  
/dev/sr0 has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label
Model: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SU-228GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 4549MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

I also forgot to mention that I have a game disk in my computer, that's sr0. And it should not be reading 'msdos,' since there is no real partition on it.

```
root@my_comp:/# lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL    UUID                                 
MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                          
├─sda1 vfat    SYSTEM   92EA-85A0                            /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                       
├─sda3 ntfs    OS       128AECEA8AECCAF5                     
├─sda4 ntfs    RECOVERY 18565C8D565C6D8E                     
├─sda5 ext4             d59773a2-e22e-4e57-945e-6d447600da16 /
└─sda6 swap             1ac79668-effe-46bc-9f71-6686c3ad8fcf [SWAP]
sr0    iso9660 BOPC_1E  2006-10-12-03-54-00-00               
/media/devepere/BOP
```

Again, there isn't a filesystem so this makes some sense.

```
root@my_comp:/# lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER       GROUP MODE
sda    931.5G YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   260M YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2    16M YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3   548G YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
├─sda4   499M YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
├─sda5 370.8G YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
└─sda6    12G YANN-MARTEL disk  brw-rw----
sr0      4.2G YANN-MARTEL cdrom brw-rw----
```

Just to clarify, I am ***completely*** overwriting the disk regularly because that's how I test my operating system. There is no partition table. My problem is that I can't write to it anymore after I receive this error: it's as if the operating system loses all ability to write to the USB drive or format it in any way.

And by the way, this happens for every USB drive I have imaged so it is definitely local to ubuntu.

**Further edits...**

## 1:

I have used the 'disk' application that comes native with linux to test formatting the usb. The error usually pops up when (or before) I do that, although it has been known to pop up sometimes shortly after boot, and consistently when I open the Microsoft partition on my disk, in which case I am using nautilus, hence a gnome application failing.

All I know is after I get the error, the USB does not respond to writing attempts. dd will run and complete, but it takes significantly less time to run and does not actually write to the disk.

## 2:

My image does contain the MBR sector with the usual ending of `0xAA55`, but **DOES NOT CONTAIN A FILE SYSTEM (OR PARTITION TABLE) OF ANY KIND**. I am creating a **COMPLETELY NEW** OPERATING SYSTEM (AND bootloader), and have not implemented a partition table yet because I would have to WRITE IT MYSELF.

## 3:

For the record, `lsblk` without flags actually does show the USB as a block before and after the error:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sdb      8:16   1   980M  0 disk 
[...]
```

And yes the size is correct; this is a rather old USB drive. I plug in my 32 gig ones, I get something that looks like 32 gigs.

And here's `lsblk -f` BEFORE the error shown triggered itself for whatever reason:

```
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL    UUID                              MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                          
├─sda1 vfat    SYSTEM   92EA-85A0                            /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                       
├─sda3 ntfs    OS       128AECEA8AECCAF5                     
├─sda4 ntfs    RECOVERY 18565C8D565C6D8E                     
├─sda5 ext4             d59773a2-e22e-4e57-945e-6d447600da16 /
└─sda6 swap             1ac79668-effe-46bc-9f71-6686c3ad8fcf [SWAP]
sdb                
sr0    iso9660 BOPC_1E  2006-10-12-03-54-00-00    
/media/devepere/BOP
```

You can clearly see that the disk (sdb) is recognized, and does not have a file system associated with it.

For further reasoning, here is what happens when i try to mount my not formatted USB disk:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

## 4:

This drive, using an MBR bootloader and not having any sort of partition table, is very hard for my UEFI boot gaming PC (one I'm using right now) to recognize. As such, I have a much older 'testing' computer that only needs the boot signature to load the bootloader into memory, since I want to actually have something to boot before I make it bootable on every machine.

As such, it cannot boot on most machines.

However, I write code on my regular computer, compile it into a binary image, and then write the image onto my usb drive. What I meant is that before the error gets triggered, this imaging process works fine.

Although when the error occurs, however it occurs, from that point on I cannot write to the USB. This is a MAJOR problem in development, because I practically cannot write 10 lines of assembly code without testing it first or else I will spend three times as much time debugging the code because I simply have no idea where it went wrong.

Thank you for your time, I know this post is extremely lengthy.

Comment: `gnome-disks` crashed, maybe because it did not understand a partition table or file system. When running the system with the USB drive connected, run some commands in a terminal window. Please edit your original question to show the output of the following command lines. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the text as 'code', which makes it easier to read. `df`; `sudo parted -ls`; `sudo lsblk -f`; `sudo lsblk -m`

Comment: Mounting a Microsoft partition should have no bearing on your ability to format the flash drive. You state that you are using `dd` but your image indicates a crash with gnome-disks. Please help us help you by [edit]ing your post to provide clarity on these points.  Clearly /dev/sdb has a partition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edits of your question :-) It seems to me, that there are tools that get confused by the content of the USB drive, when you have cloned your system into it. I think that some signatures are identified, and conclusions are drawn. But it is based on a mistake, the conclusions are wrong, and the actions will fail severely. I cannot tell what goes wrong and how to fix it. I'm sorry, but this is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Maybe, if you unplug the USB drive after cloning, and plug it into another computer with a simpler operating system (for example made from the Ubuntu `mini.iso`, and where you have added only a few necessary tools), you could keep it from crashing, and have a detailed look at it without having to reboot your main computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the cause of the problem is that sometimes I forgot to plug my USB in when using `dd`, or the USB port itself was loose.

I added the following lines to the shell script I was using that compiled my program and ran the `dd` command:

```
lsusb -d 0781:5530
! [[ $? = 0 ]] && { echo "please plug in the sandisk cruzer usb before proceeding"; exit 1; }
```

A long and detailed explanation:

`lsusb` lists all the USBs avaliable, or a subset of them depending on your arguments. I get the usb by the specific product number, which means I can only use one specific usb unless I change the value. For example, that particular number corrolates with my sandisk cruzer, so I can only plug that one in unless I run `lsusb` without arguments, check to see where my usb is, and get the ID and replace it with the old one.

If `lsusb` does not find the specific device, it returns with an error code. The `$?` holds that error code, and is in general in shell scripting the exit code of the process last ran. Linux processes (and others as well I would imagine) return 0 on successful, so on an unsuccessful run (aka the usb is not plugged in), it will return something other than 0.

The `[[ (condition) ]]` represents a conditional in bash scripting, and the `!` represents the NOT operator, in other words, if the condition returned true or false, the `!` will return the opposite. Note: don't use `==` when comparing.

The `&&` operator basically says execute whatever is to the right of the program if the previous conditional is true. `||` works the same way except when the condition returns false, by the way.

`{ (command); (command); ... }` is a block of commands to execute one after the other. The output of the first command does not feed into the second; it is just like a list. You could also make a function acheive the same purpose.

`echo` is the same as it always has been: just spits out the text taken as an argument.

`exit 1` ends the program with an error code of `1` (because it failed). It comes last because you want the echo to run BEFORE you end the program.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) (I could not guess the cause of your problem.)

Comment: I could not either, so no hard feelings. You're welcome